# Why I can not parse an Object structure from a valid JSON file in Testing framework

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

All:

I save an object structure into a JSON like:

**myjson.json**

```
{
  "name":"hello",
  "attr":{
    "a1":"a1",
    "a2":"a2"
  },
  "attrArray": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

then when I use either jQuery or Angular to get it, I always get error like:

```
$.get("myjson.json").done(function(data){});
$http.get("myjson.json").then(function(data){})

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Right now, the only way make it work is to wrap this object with array like:

```
[{
  "name":"hello",
  "attr":{
    "a1":"a1",
    "a2":"a2"
  },
  "attrArray": [1,2,3,4]
}]
```

But I really wonder how to **make them recognize this object style JSON format and parse it**?

**NOTE: All above is in Karma testing, if I just use those code without test framework, then everything works**

Comment: If that is your code, you should not be having issues. If you access the file directly in the browser, does it load?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it loads. The error only happens when I use jquery or angular to get it

Comment: Are you serving the file from the file system or from a web server?

Comment: @BrunoS. From Server, I run this code in Karma

Comment: Is that your exact code for your get functions? That's all you have in there? Because if not, we really need to see the rest of the functions.

Comment: @kevindeleon Thanks, my actual code is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067853/why-i-got-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-about-the-json-file

Comment: Why do you have two questions on the same exact thing?

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, because some people are only asking questions like "Why do you have ..." rather than help to find and share answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `responseType` option with angular:

```
$http.get('myjson.json', {responseType: 'json'}).then(function(response) {});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works even without {responseType: 'json'} if not run inside Karma testing, but in Karma( like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067853/why-i-got-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-about-the-json-file) it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your server should send file as  Content-Type `application/json`, also you can try use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead of `$.get`

Comment: Thanks, I tried getJSON, but not works. Right now, I actually run this code in Karma(which means Karma load this json file), I wonder how to config Karma to add that content-type ?

Comment: And what about response Content type header?

Comment: thanks, the response header is like: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 17:55:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked